# Chamar arquivo php sem sair da página com HTML

Tags: php, html, aplicação-web

Gostaria de fazer um botão com a tag < a > do html para chamar um código php externo.

**Exemplo**

```
<a href="arquivo.php">
```

No qual o arquivo.php seria apenas alguns comandos, que eu gostaria apenas de executa-los sem abrir realmente um página, pois quando isso ocorre a única saída que vi seria um refresh para outra página, que no caso faria um reload indesejado.

Comment: Conhece Ajax???

Comment: Esse é o problema, vi alguns exemplos de AJAX mas não achei muito conveniente, visto que tenho pouca utilização para ele no meu aplicativo, até agora seria só essa no caso. Tenho bastante dificuldade com scripts, gostaria de algo que fugisse do AJAX, caso seja realmente a única opção tentarei implementa-lo novamente.

Comment: Você diz na sua pergunta que um reload é indesejado, o ajax vai resolver seu problema em relação a isso. Fique tranquilo em relação a dificuldade, é mais simples do que parece isso você pode ter certeza.

Comment: Caso você queira um exemplo em ajax, posso dar uma resposta com o uso dele, posso também explicar de forma simples mas entendedora e você verá que é uma coisa muito simples.

Comment: Lembrado que o php é server-side, isso significa que ele será executado no servidor e depois virá como resultado na página. Eu desconheço outra forma tão simples de fazer essa execução se não com Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso você pode utilizar requisições **Ajax**, acredito que seria a única opção para o seu caso. Para facilitar o trabalho utilize a biblioteca [jQuery](https://jquery.com). Supondo que você já tenha incluído a biblioteca em sua página, vamos a alguns exemplos:

Para executar um código PHP externo:

```
$.get( "test.php" );
```

Caso precise passar algum parâmetro para o script:

```
$.get( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

Caso precise pegar algum dado de retorno:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
  alert( "Retorno: " + data );
});
```

o **jQuery.get()** ou **$.get()** equivale a **jQuery.ajax()** ou **$.ajax()** em termos de funcionamento, entretanto, seria "mas" simples de usar. Documentação: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Além do **$.get()** você pode optar por **$.ajax()** conforme listado acima, caso necessite de mais recursos. Documentação: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/